# Crashlytics logging of Swift Try-Catch

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics

I'm facing a weird issue where Crashlytics is logging caught exceptions from within a try-catch block.
Here's some sample code:

```
        do {
            try managedContext.save() // Exception!!!
        } catch let error as NSError {
            error = error
            print("Could not save \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")
        }
```

The try-catch block is supposed to prevent crashes, and yet this line is logged by Crashlytics as an issue (and NOT a non-fatal). How is this possible?

Some background info:

1. The `managedContext` object is of type `NSManagedObjectContext`, which is initialized by the AppDelegate (written in Objective-C).
2. I'm using the latest version of Fabric - 2.3.0

What's going on?

Comment: Swift try-catch blocks are for swift errors, not objective-c exceptions.  You can't catch objective-c exceptions from Swift

Comment: But this particular line is Swift code. How would you suggest I handle this?

Comment: Depends on what the exception is

Comment: It's a Core Data migration failure. "Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores (schema mismatch or migration failure)".
My goal is to catch any possible exception triggered by that line (Swift) - I still don't understand how the underlying Objective-C interoperation is an issue.

Comment: You need to fix the underlying error causing the exception, or write that code in objective-c.  You can't catch the exceptions if you are using Swift.

Comment: Alright, thank you. This seems quite a drawback of having an app with a mix of Objective-C and Swift.

Comment: I'd suggest writing a small category for NSManagedObjectContext in obj-c that tries to save context, and caches the exception, and then returns either true of false.